# SUM in Oracle: return NULL only when all fields are NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a rather complicated select query that contains two types of SUM expressions. The Simple SUM:

```
SUM(X)
```

And the more complicated SUM/CASE:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE IN (
    'ORANGES',
    'LEMONS',
    'LIMES')
    THEN X
    ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_CITRUS
```

Now, here's the problem: I need both of these SUMS to evaluate to NULL **only** if all of the values summed are null. If any one of the values summed is a value then the sum needs to be returned as if all null values were substituted for 0.

For the cases shown, how might this be achieved? My concerns are efficiency and simplicity, in that order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need both of these SUMS to evaluate to NULL only if all of the
>   values summed are null.

It will by default. Just replace `0` with `null` in your `ELSE` condition.

```
    09:43:30 SYSTEM@dwal> ed
Wrote file S:\spool\dwal\BUFFER_SYSTEM_65.sql

  1  with t (x, y) as (
  2    select null, 1  from dual union all
  3    select null, 1  from dual union all
  4    select null, 2 from dual
  5  )
  6* select sum(x), sum(case y when 1 then x else null end ) from t
09:43:40 SYSTEM@dwal> /

    SUM(X) SUM(CASEYWHEN1THENXELSENULLEND)
---------- -------------------------------


Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
09:43:41 SYSTEM@dwal> 2
  2*   select null, 1  from dual union all
09:43:59 SYSTEM@dwal> c/null/1
  2*   select 1, 1  from dual union all
09:44:03 SYSTEM@dwal> /

    SUM(X) SUM(CASEYWHEN1THENXELSENULLEND)
---------- -------------------------------
         1                               1

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Comment: Ah, Thank you! it appears that the reference I was using for the behavior of the SUM expression was misleading. Making the change you've suggested is all  that was required.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle itself is doing what you want: for `sum()`, if all elements are null, sum() will return null

Therefore, you should be able to do something like:

```
SELECT FOO,
SUM(CASE 
      WHEN TYPE IN (
        'ORANGES',
        'LEMONS',
        'LIMES') THEN X
      WHEN TYPE IS NULL THEN NULL
      ELSE 0 
     END) AS SUM_CITRUS
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY FOO
```

(Here I assume there are lots of different other type, and you want orange/lemon/limes to count as X, other type count as 0, null count as null)